# PHP - Fetch value based on what is selected from option

Tags: javascript, php, html, select

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="mscr_type" id="mscr_type">

            <?php $fpp_type = '';
                  foreach ($getmilestone_cr as $mscr_list) {

                  $description = $mscr_list['FIX_PRJ_DESC'];//fetch  description

                    if ($fpp_type != $mscr_list['FIX_PRJ_TYPE']) {
                        if ($fpp_type != '') {
                            echo '</optgroup>';
                    }

                    if($mscr_list['FIX_PRJ_TYPE'] == 'MS'):
                        echo $fpp_label = "Milestone";
                    elseif($mscr_list['FIX_PRJ_TYPE'] == 'CR'):
                        echo $fpp_label = "Change Request(CR)";
                    endif;

                    echo '<optgroup label="'.$fpp_label.'">';

                    }

                    echo '<option value="'.$mscr_list['FIX_PRJ_TYPE'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($mscr_list['FIX_PRJ_NAME']).'</option>';
                    $fpp_type = $mscr_list['FIX_PRJ_TYPE'];    
                }

                    if ($fpp_type != '') {
                        echo '</optgroup>';
                    }
            ?>
</select>
```

**The above code outputs:**

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <optgroup label="Picnic">
      <option value ="1">Mustard</option>
      <option value ="2">Ketchup</option>
      <option value ="3">Relish</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Camping">
      <option value ="4">Tent</option>
      <option value ="5">Flashlight</option>
      <option value ="6">Toilet Paper</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
```

How could I fetch description based on what is selected from selected option. For example if Mustard is selected, then input value should be filled
with value 'Mustard is yellow in color'.

Tried using `<select class="selectpicker" name="mscr_type" id="mscr_type" onchange="document.getElementById('mscr_description').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">` but it fetches the name and not description.

```
<label for="name" class="label">Description</label>  
<input type="text" disabled="" id="selectpicker_description" name="selectpicker_description" class="span3">
```

Comment: Where are the descriptions in the HTML?

Comment: `Description` would be text based on the value selected from dropdown. Like for `mustard` it has `data id=1,name='Mustard' and desc = 'Some description'` So if a user selects Mustard, the  description input will be autopopulated with its relevant description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the description to the HTML using a `data-XXX` attribute:

```
echo '<option value="'.$mscr_list['FIX_PRJ_TYPE'].'" data-description="'.htmlspecialchars($description).'">'.htmlspecialchars($mscr_list['FIX_PRJ_NAME']).'</option>';
```

Then you can use

```
onchange="updateDescription(this)"
```

with the Javascript function:

```
function updateDescription(sel) {
    var output = document.getElementById('mscr_description');
    var desc = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-description');
    output.value = desc;
}
```

Comment: It says - `TypeError: sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].attr is not a function`

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally used a jQuery function. Fixed it.

Comment: Yup, I was about to comment that. Its fixed.